# Apple Calendar and Google Calendar URL incompatatability URL too long

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I do have a question I have a long `URL` defined, it has up to 400 chars in it, so `Apple Calendar` do not format it correctly and you can only click on part of it in description(picture below):

[image]

So I have moved it to `URL` field in `ics` file, so it would be clickable, but now this `URL` is not shown on `Google Calendar` if it synced with `Apple Calendar`

ICS file look like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20210915T084245Z
DTSTART:20210915T160000Z
DTEND:20210915T200000Z
SUMMARY:Zoom
UID:de61f319-deba-4906-b964-81cbb39fad0e
DESCRIPTION: Join Zoom Meeting: https://www.zoom.com/op?join=JWS.eyJraWQiOiJpb21iOUJ0eSIsImFsZwI6IkhTMjU2un0.eyJkYXRhIjoie1wiYWN0aW9uXCI6XCJqb2luXCIsXCJpbnN0YW5jZUlkXCI6XCI3NzVkYzA4Mi1kOTNhLTQxaDAtODM2Ni0xMmZiMzQ4NjY4Y2FcIixcImV2ZW50SWRcIjpcIjIxNGViNTE5LTdhZTYtNGZhMC1iYzgxLWFmZDRlOGRkzmViZVwiLFwiZ3Vlc3RJZFwiOlwiMDg4NThkMDctNDMyYS00NDNmLWFkOTQtMmM4YTk5NDEzYjMyXCIsXCJuYW1lXCI6XCJUZXN0IFVzZXJcIn0iLCJpYXQiOjE2Mjk5Njk5MzR9.Gn8lB5jnTI5Q6rlqTNgZM92PBUKo2r1k9urJScKLLSI
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I thought maybe I could somehow do a universal `ICS` file for 3 calendars like Apple, Outlook and google:

For Apple I could reuse `URL` field. (for google it does not show)

For Microsoft Outlook I could reuse `X-ALT-DESC;` (for google it does not show)

For Google is there a seperate `Description` field which I could reuse?

Or maybe is there another way how could I fix this issue, so all the users across all calendars could see this `URL` without any problem?

Comment: Could you use a URL shortener and paste this link instead?